# Jquery ajax request showing json object instead of alerting

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, forms, model-view-controller

After submitting the form, Json object is displayed instead of alert. What I need is an alert box displaying success message or error. But on submitting the form, it only displays returned JSON object. This is my MVC controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(Subscriber Sub)
    {
        KeyGenerator Validate = new KeyGenerator();
        string Email = Sub.Username.Trim();
        bool IsValid = Validate.ValidateEmail(Email);
        ENT Ent = new ENT();
        if (IsValid)
        {
            Subscriber SubEmail = Ent.Subscribers.Where(a => a.Username == Email).FirstOrDefault();
            if (SubEmail != null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Already subscribed!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                Ent.AddToSub(Email);
                return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Thank you." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Invalid request." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

This is my ajax request:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
        $("#subscribe").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var values = new FormData($(this));
        $.ajax({
               type: $(this).type,
               url: $(this).action,
               data: values,
               processData: false,
               contentType: false,
               cache: false,
               success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }                          
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
             });
        
    });
```

How to display alert instead of the JSON object?
My JSON response is as follows:

```
{"success":true,"responseText":"Thank you."}
```

**Also, is this because requesting page is PHP?
The page on which request is made is on https://MyWebUrl.com(Not real url)
which is in PHP
and MVC website is on https://MySubDomain.MyWebUrl.com(Not real url)
Is this the reason?**

Comment: maybe try converting the response to a json object `let json = JSON.parse(response);` and then see if it allows you to get the property `alert(json.ResponseText);` I know you are returning a json object from the controller, but its worth a try.

Comment: I did this but still didn't work. Check my edit please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the solution but this works for me. Due to the reason listed in the bold letters in my question, I did some changes.
I changed my MVC action as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(Subscriber Sub)
    {
        KeyGenerator Validate = new KeyGenerator();
        string Email = Sub.Username.Trim();
        bool IsValid = Validate.ValidateEmail(Email);
        ENT Ent = new ENT();
        if (IsValid)
        {
            Subscriber SubEmail = Ent.Subscribers.Where(a => a.Username.ToLower() == Email.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (SubEmail != null)
            {
                //return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Already subscribed!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return RedirectToAction("ViewSubMsg", new { id = "Already subscribed!" });
            }
            else
            {
                Ent.AddToSub(Email);
                //return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Thank you." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return RedirectToAction("ViewSubMsg", new { id = "Thank you!" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Invalid request!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return RedirectToAction("ViewSubMsg", new { id = "Invalid request!" });
        }
    }
```

Then I added a new action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ViewSubMsg(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return Redirect("mysiteurl");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Msg = id;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And its view:

```
//View    
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ViewSubMsg</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("@ViewBag.Msg");
            window.location.replace("mysiteurl");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```